# Javascript - divide by spaces unless within brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to divide a string by spaces, but only if the spaces are not within square brackets.
For example:

> "What a [nice sunny] day"

After dividing, it should look like this:

> [What, a, [nice sunny], day]

I tried to find the solution on my own, but I'm afraid I'm not enough familiar with RegExp in javascript.

Comment: `"What a [nice sunny] day".match(/(^|\s)(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/g)`.

Comment: `"What a [nice sunny] day".match(/\[[^\]]*\]|[\S]+/g)`

Comment: Borrowing from @GGG, `var yourstring = yourstring.match(/(\[[^\]]*\]|[\S]+)/ig).join(', ');`

Comment: Thank you all for quick responses! All of them worked very well, but GGG's version did exactly what I wanted. How do I accept it as a correct answer?

Comment: Leave a message in the format @GGG to notify him that there's a comment, and leave a message asking him to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: @user1377881 mark Rob W's, he beat me by a few seconds on the first comment :)

Comment: @GGG `[\S]+` is equivalent to `\S+`. Any reason that you used `[\S]` instead of `\S`?

Comment: @RobW nope, those are leftovers, I had some other stuff in there when I was playing with it in the console. I tried to edit it out but the comments wouldn't let me. =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the space has to be included, the following RegEx is needed:

```
"What a [nice sunny] day".match(/(^|\s)(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/g)
// Outputs: ["What"," a"," [nice sunny]"," day"]
```

In the comments, it became obvious that the spaces have to be removed:

```
"What a [nice sunny] day".match(/\[[^\]]+\]|\S+/g)
// Outputs: ["What","a","[nice sunny]","day"]
```